# How to add a meshgrid to a plotly 3d surface?

Tags: plotly, mesh, plotly-python, surface

I'm trying to add a grid to a 3D surface generated by using plotly.
The end result should look something like this:
[image]

My current code looks like this:

```
df_interpolated_annual = ma_df.interpolate(method='linear')

fig_annual = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(
    z=df_interpolated_annual.values,
    x=df_interpolated_annual.columns,
    y=df_interpolated_annual.index,
    colorscale=colorscale
)])
fig_annual.update_layout(title='Annual', scene=dict(
    xaxis=dict(title='Variable1', ticktext=df_interpolated_annual.columns.tolist(), tickvals=list(range(len(df_interpolated_annual.columns))), tickfont=dict(size=12)),
    yaxis=dict(title='Date', tickfont=dict(size=12)), 
    zaxis=dict(title='Variable2', tickfont=dict(size=12)), 
    aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=0.7)
    ),
    width=1000, 
    height=1000
)
fig_annual.show()
```

Which gives me the following result:
[image]

I tried to add a grid with the following code:

```py
fig_annual = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(
    z=df_interpolated_annual.values,
    x=df_interpolated_annual.columns,
    y=df_interpolated_annual.index,
    colorscale=colorscale
)])

x, y = df_interpolated_annual.columns, df_interpolated_annual.index
z = df_interpolated_annual.values

fig_annual.add_trace(go.Mesh3d(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    z=z,
    color='red',
    opacity=1,
    showlegend=False
))

fig_annual.update_layout(title='Annual', scene=dict(
    xaxis=dict(title='Variable1', ticktext=x.tolist(), tickvals=list(range(len(x))), tickfont=dict(size=12), showgrid=True),
    yaxis=dict(title='Date', tickfont=dict(size=12), showgrid=True), 
    zaxis=dict(title='Variable2', tickfont=dict(size=12), showgrid=True), 
    aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=0.7)
    ),
    width=1000, 
    height=1000
)

fig_annual.show()
```

However, this did not change the output.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

We can generate the grid overlaying the surface by combining two [wireframe plots](https://plotly.com/python/v3/3d-wireframe-plots/) where all of the lines in one wireframe are perpendicular to all of the lines in the other wireframe.

To do this, we construct meshgrids from your x and y arrays in one direction using `xGrid, yGrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)`, and the other direction using `xRevGrid, yRevGrid = np.meshgrid(y, x)`. Then iterate through both of these grids, adding each `(x,y,z)` coordinate as a `go.Scatter3d` trace with the argument `mode='lines'`.

Note that the x and y coordinate types need to be consistent between both forward and reverse grids (and in this example, I've shown that it works with dates on one axis, and categorical values on another axis, like your data appears to be).

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Read data from a csv
# use x and y ranges specific to the data
x = pd.date_range('2023-01-01', periods=25)
y = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('y')+1)]
z_data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x=x, y=y, z=z_data.values)])

xGrid, yGrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
xRevGrid, yRevGrid = np.meshgrid(y, x)
line_marker = dict(color='black', width=2)

## add gridlines in one direction using mesh grid
for i, j, k in zip(xGrid, yGrid, z_data.values):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=i, y=j, z=k, mode='lines', line=line_marker, showlegend=False)) # this works

## add gridlines in perpendicular direction using reverse mesh grid
for i, j, k in zip(xRevGrid, yRevGrid, z_data.values.T):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=j, y=i, z=k, mode='lines', line=line_marker, showlegend=False)) # this doesn't work

fig.update_layout(title='Mt Bruno Elevation', autosize=True,
                  scene_camera_eye=dict(x=1.87, y=0.88, z=-0.64),
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90)
)

fig.show()
```

[image]