# How to add a grid overlay to a 3D plotly in R?

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, surface, wireframe

I am trying to create a 3D plot with grid over the top of the data (similar to this example: [How to add a meshgrid to a plotly 3d surface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75675768/how-to-add-a-meshgrid-to-a-plotly-3d-surface)) but no matter what i try, it isnt working. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Any advice is much appreciated.

Here is the code i am using:

```
# Response surface (with grid on axes)
x <- plot_ly(PredDat, x = ~est, y = ~Day, z = ~percent,
             intensity = ~percent,
             colorscale = list(c(0,'green'),
                               c(0.05,'yellow'),
                               c(0.1, 'orange'),
                               c(1, 'red')),
             type = 'mesh3d')
x <- x %>% layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(type = "log", title = 'Concentration (ug/L)', showgrid = TRUE, gridcolor = "black"),
                               yaxis = list(title = 'Day', showgrid = TRUE, gridcolor = "black"),
                               zaxis = list(title = 'percent affected', showgrid = TRUE, gridcolor = "black")))
x
```

Which produces this plot:

[image]

My data has the following structure:

```
> summary(sampleData)
    percent      est                  Day        
 Min.   : 1.00   Min.   :    0.000   Min.   :  1.00  
 1st Qu.:23.75   1st Qu.:    0.064   1st Qu.:  9.00  
 Median :54.50   Median :    0.955   Median : 17.00  
 Mean   :52.27   Mean   :  225.022   Mean   : 64.51  
 3rd Qu.:77.00   3rd Qu.:    9.612   3rd Qu.: 50.00  
 Max.   :99.00   Max.   :16382.540   Max.   :350.00
```

dput just in case that is easier:

```
> dput(sampleData)
structure(list(percent = c(63L, 85L, 82L, 49L, 88L, 95L, 88L, 
84L, 8L, 99L, 41L, 20L, 55L, 51L, 56L, 18L, 45L, 39L, 18L, 78L, 
57L, 44L, 20L, 74L, 90L, 7L, 68L, 22L, 94L, 35L, 70L, 1L, 15L, 
47L, 78L, 47L, 92L, 14L, 96L, 42L, 23L, 63L, 89L, 58L, 87L, 49L, 
38L, 49L, 56L, 73L, 25L, 54L, 97L, 4L, 99L, 56L, 54L, 1L, 4L, 
20L, 75L, 92L, 85L, 89L, 22L, 76L, 85L, 75L, 13L, 13L, 77L, 46L, 
56L, 11L, 45L, 35L, 84L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 71L, 20L, 15L, 94L, 21L, 
79L, 53L, 75L, 57L, 45L, 63L, 72L, 63L, 21L, 74L, 66L, 79L, 98L, 
19L, 97L, 72L, 50L, 86L, 69L, 65L, 91L, 88L, 3L, 34L, 9L, 81L, 
65L, 45L, 13L, 70L, 37L, 81L, 7L, 71L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 91L, 98L, 
49L, 71L, 12L, 63L, 73L, 26L, 20L, 54L, 28L, 64L, 89L, 77L, 51L, 
26L, 62L, 63L, 76L, 25L, 73L, 8L, 53L, 10L, 86L, 19L, 46L, 20L, 
90L, 77L, 8L, 28L, 79L, 34L, 31L, 15L, 87L, 87L, 77L, 1L, 29L, 
53L, 82L, 44L, 8L, 20L, 68L, 85L, 91L, 6L, 77L, 30L, 6L, 22L, 
95L, 92L, 65L, 54L, 58L, 61L, 98L, 74L, 49L, 87L, 42L, 46L, 45L, 
28L, 32L, 7L, 62L, 35L, 24L, 12L, 74L, 68L, 71L, 58L), est = c(1.04407485232684, 
15.9422865186523, 21.8097901217244, 0.624061160609868, 137.758650998872, 
1803.87637210633, 0.760192433809832, 0.414478264297407, 0.0452467657381889, 
16382.5401402268, 0.00441304252959353, 0.00241295675163572, 0.994838821417042, 
1.79258605469963, 0.513004900664426, 0.0770323004997502, 0.025809346390113, 
0.0133350482825202, 0.8335392718973, 2.49033296236117, 1.20919695813704, 
0.713393261649366, 0.0895658895371724, 9.5887846390835, 38.1734185089705, 
0.021467239694851, 1.28768040659316, 0.200309232297262, 3271.45503789688, 
3.84465569672239, 3.24711941679096, 0.0111159045915617, 0.0415015162604063, 
0.510156595331072, 11.4562721994463, 0.00643459855069155, 1717.3524984109, 
0.241532532773892, 2.05002142540291, 1.5143998596384, 0.000270702976191344, 
4.22613920026973, 1.00710427067479, 2.9047941635375, 4.89326455569652, 
0.659650724858752, 0.952891055604006, 0.00672668982765519, 2.51984332684414, 
6.61606524688289, 0.183850270389014, 0.41968794803407, 613.822979083032, 
0.00987130162078365, 5.49410642957213, 2.13426353436643, 0.0311582669288472, 
2.45704794843697e-05, 0.104871882328571, 0.0240328611419533, 
22.6487599991652, 61.7103654408549, 20.8664072256021, 31.109478318259, 
0.0013145762931139, 0.276312784742751, 1230.11276833219, 351.332582939509, 
0.00735226683287831, 0.0573946550168844, 15.4663524704398, 0.00551333301462274, 
75.4733480046846, 0.0541199633388947, 0.450876010909864, 0.0465558377756151, 
69.0420619440199, 0.0326080067237438, 2.35817429782289, 0.00205082752760487, 
7.13703981774009, 0.00803477701816285, 0.0363879430802282, 160.560674451424, 
0.00867054501275599, 64.0940155981017, 1.73344175905959, 7.25339311177785, 
1.7196630588627, 0.66737236404782, 2.3969677782588, 5.31938373229231, 
5.0674560906683, 0.525345148814841, 4.81678065649555, 2.3231224341502, 
23.2040648865511, 1565.31575271191, 7.49798237833499, 15125.2816672554, 
3.83716998913727, 0.0158853750584201, 123.544523295717, 3.12852310907506, 
0.0983352986516117, 348.246042942081, 43.8366596677592, 0.53311119445624, 
0.330365574177749, 0.0984589727560102, 18.9895060704893, 2.25561904124953, 
0.00477499031873687, 0.000294567963473975, 11.1248255984764, 
0.00100877519812577, 0.386293426910268, 0.0465262379905129, 12.1853067335855, 
0.000359636279803776, 0.0010901640739526, 0.252962117322107, 
1.5931599419431, 3.11897366350088, 0.00506088115778639, 0.342454771476626, 
0.203903549331277, 0.910175855744087, 5.27270018754817, 0.136732557101739, 
0.000203375937630994, 0.0642936643751398, 0.000822344867368876, 
2.08387043796528, 97.3238032721882, 0.249618461207728, 0.0311505378973044, 
0.0126566639447543, 9.6834496873792, 0.192839064290056, 16.453454277487, 
0.00378897335137911, 4.44281773980034, 0.000145357666547522, 
0.375842504318371, 0.0280639336070094, 17.4902503513962, 0.00056095897156569, 
0.630852788108575, 0.0635845223499213, 564.986667712194, 51.1306086562373, 
0.0246691360475172, 1.11476326965692, 0.337453194277694, 0.378281449110894, 
1.3398790432204, 0.207956166495869, 26.6078879076572, 23.6593931463183, 
78.6316938631263, 0.00175420263945739, 0.187032110123746, 0.817631721338736, 
15.5886060559813, 0.553472314050031, 0.0730856839941687, 0.957610566174482, 
15.554585131796, 8.4071956356968, 62.7594685395332, 6.36145826749089e-05, 
18.3728100876976, 0.000514793790291854, 0.0690791969176382, 0.000745771369488229, 
142.966809774615, 82.4629194527887, 49.4430010923703, 3.26254308054076, 
10.251010970077, 8.9942750877235, 3.85291157047756, 107.184132364844, 
4.00244348090398, 2.01400970149377, 0.408075094375508, 1.56682298054436, 
0.87718928574718, 0.000428593686118138, 0.157988307382218, 0.511348418441622, 
1.7040487465029, 20.513022659987, 0.11394610962745, 0.0346824155021124, 
13.3414141457494, 1.89276239553076, 0.196405473851736, 0.614362904839189
), Day = c(40L, 19L, 11L, 19L, 6L, 4L, 250L, 350L, 13L, 15L, 
200L, 100L, 19L, 9L, 50L, 16L, 100L, 100L, 4L, 50L, 15L, 12L, 
16L, 10L, 19L, 17L, 50L, 11L, 2L, 3L, 20L, 13L, 19L, 20L, 12L, 
250L, 2L, 7L, 200L, 7L, 350L, 9L, 200L, 9L, 50L, 18L, 8L, 300L, 
9L, 12L, 13L, 50L, 18L, 20L, 150L, 10L, 250L, 150L, 6L, 30L, 
6L, 19L, 16L, 19L, 150L, 300L, 1L, 1L, 40L, 15L, 9L, 250L, 1L, 
14L, 19L, 40L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 50L, 10L, 50L, 20L, 17L, 50L, 4L, 
10L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 6L, 16L, 19L, 8L, 18L, 1L, 
2L, 19L, 200L, 5L, 18L, 350L, 5L, 14L, 2L, 13L, 9L, 11L, 18L, 
250L, 200L, 7L, 350L, 300L, 12L, 7L, 250L, 150L, 10L, 150L, 200L, 
350L, 200L, 7L, 50L, 14L, 16L, 350L, 150L, 250L, 18L, 9L, 350L, 
150L, 50L, 5L, 200L, 8L, 100L, 18L, 200L, 50L, 18L, 20L, 200L, 
14L, 19L, 3L, 4L, 17L, 5L, 300L, 12L, 5L, 8L, 17L, 18L, 3L, 30L, 
15L, 16L, 14L, 14L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 30L, 17L, 250L, 8L, 350L, 9L, 
200L, 20L, 17L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 150L, 2L, 5L, 100L, 17L, 8L, 
11L, 350L, 19L, 3L, 17L, 1L, 17L, 18L, 8L, 30L, 300L, 50L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-200L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: Do you mean contour lines?

Comment: yes exactly.. the plot in the image is correct, i would just like to add contour lines over the top of the surface.